# Customize Bluetooth Pairing Request message on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to customize the Bluetooth Pairing Request dialog on iOS? This is what we get currently for our Bluetooth device. Basically, there is no numerically entry on our Bluetooth device. You press a button on our device to confirm pairing. However, I'm not clear if you need to make a change on the firmware or if this is something that can be customized from iOS to change the text.

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the pairing dialog. It is presented by iOS. It looks like your device is using pass key pairing, which isn't really appropriate for a device that is incapable of displaying the pass key it is using. Out of band pairing may be more appropriate, but you will need to communicate the pairing pin to the user somehow, either via sticker on the device or in product documentation.  You could also use "just works" pairing